# Handmade Product In UK

Tags: patentability, european

If a product is handmade in the UK, not sold in the united states, does not have a patent, can that product ne created and patented in the states?

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not the product is handmade is of no consequence. Once a product is disclosed publicly it no longer becomes patentable. A few countries such as the US have a grace period which allows filing a patent within a period after disclosure (12 months for the US). However, for most of the world, you no longer can pursue a patent. If a product is disclosed outside the US is still counts as prior art within the US. So the bottom line is if you have been selling the product for more than a year, you can't obtain a US patent.

Even if the product has been for sale less than one year, you may or may not be able to obtain a patent depending on whether the invention meets the requirements of patentability.